# How to test significance of polynomial (linear) trends among groups with unequal variances?

Tags: r, spss, anova, variance, trendline

I am testing for a linear trend among several groups, however, my data has violated the assumption of equal variance among groups (tested by Levene's homogeneity of variance).

In SPSS, along with the significance of linear trend assuming equal variance, there is automatic output for significance where equal variances are *not* assumed. What 'test' or 'adjustment' is being done? Can I do this in R, and how?

Image of SPSS output: (https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZRs3EM3wJz5raHhav-LLBTmTyfLJO0z4xHDEzI-3uI15BoBQ5)

I'm struggling to find what exactly SPSS is doing, but it could be some sort of welch correction?

```
# TEST homogeneity of variance
leveneTest(ICECAP_A ~ SFMental_f, data = SCI)
```

p < 0.001 so we reject null of homogeneity of variance.

```
# Use built-in contr.poly() function: Tell R to get a polynomial contrast matrix for 5 levels/groups
contrasts(SCI$SFMental_f) <- contr.poly(n=5)

# call an ANOVA
anova.SFMental <- aov(ICECAP_A ~ SFMental_f, data = SCI)

# print output, show linear trend result
summary.aov(anova.SFMental, split=list (SFMental_f=list ("Linear"=1)))
```

Now I have the significance for linear trend. How do I get the significance if we do NOT assume equal variances?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SPSS does a correction using the [Welch-Satterthwaite Equation][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation_). Thanks to Andy Field for the tip. But there is no direct R alternative, so I constructed the contrasts in the usual way and ran a robust model with `lmRob()` instead.